Getting Information Inside <div>
I want to get the text information in a div on a site.
Web Page

Div Information I Want to Get
<div class="package-status-header s3">Transit olarak</div>

I want to use php html dom. Thanks for solving this problem for me.
The Codes I Used Are Like This
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$site =  "https://pkge.net/tr/parcel/7330017657196779";
$html = file_get_html($site);

foreach ($html->find('#container') as $element) {
    $gelenlink = $element->find('s3', 1)->src;
    echo "Link  : ".$gelenlink."<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
}


find('s3') looks for an element like <s3>. If you want to find by class, you need to use .s3. And it has no src attribute, you want ->innertext.

to add to the above comment. I would look for the class "package-status-header" instead of "s3" as s3 looks like a more generic class that has more chance to appear on other elements. Something like: "$element->find('.package-status-header', 0)->innertext()"

@yumlusoft what is your current issue? nothing returns?

What I want to do is get text inside the div
https://pkge.net/tr/parcel/7330017657196779
I want to get the text file that I mentioned above on the page. My codes may be wrong, can you correct it?

i think no one can solve this problem of mine
